# How do get Student class name (eg-2018-Math-1BE) in attendance module when selecting date (refering from timetable)?

Tags: python, odoo, erp

```
class EducationStudentsAttendance(models.Model):
    _name = 'education.attendances'

name = fields.Char(compute='get_name', string='Attendance Sheet Name', default='New')
    # class_id = fields.Many2one('education.class', string='Class')
    class_division = fields.Many2one('education.class.division', string='Class', required=True)
    date = fields.Date(string='Date', default=fields.Date.today, required=True)
    attendance_line = fields.One2many('education.attendances.line', 'attendance_id', string='Attendance Line')
    attendance_created = fields.Boolean(string='Attendance Created')
    state = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('done', 'Done')], default='draft')
    academic_year = fields.Many2one('education.academic.year', string='Academic Year',
                                    related='class_division.academic_year_id', store=True)

    # add fields to relate timetable
    week_day = fields.Char('Week Day')
    subject = fields.Many2one('education.subject', string='Subject', required=True)
```

"""Here How do I get class_division when creating in timetable ?"""

Comment: Here timetable module.....

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the Onchange API
see this example

```
    @api.onchange('date')
    def set_name(self):
        self.name = ('Your Text %s - %s') % (self.date, self.subject )
```